# Losing object's reference inside EJB class

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, ejb-3.1, object-reference

I have a REST service that receives a JSON, converts to Object and sends it to an EJB. The problem is when the method inside EJB is called, all attributes from my objects are null..

It's look like that the object reference is being lost:

- Reference inside REST class:

```
entities.login.Usuario@8d744cc7
```

- Reference inside EJB:

```
entities.login.Usuario@a1
```

I've overrided the equals and hashCode from my class Usuario:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "usuario")
@JsonRootName(value = "usuario")
@Entity
@Table(name = "USUARIO")
public class Usuario implements Entidade {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4638207002664824130L;
...


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj != null && (obj instanceof Usuario)  && ((Usuario) obj).getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(this.getEmail())){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 23 * hash + ((getEmail()) != null ? getEmail().hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}
}
```

My REST class:

```
@Path("/usuario")
public class UsuarioRest {
    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response login(Usuario usuario){     
        return Response.ok(usuarioService.getUsuario(usuario)).build();
    }
}
```

Any ideas what's going on? I'm using Java 7, EJB 3.1, REST 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Glassfish? Are you have all files in one WAR file?

Comment: Glassfish 4!

No, i have an EAR with my JPA and EJB...and i have 2 web modules ( WAR ) that are deployed isolated!